# Display dynamic mysql table from radio button input using json

Tags: java, jquery, html, json, servlets

i have a form with radio buttons, when clicked i pass it to a servlet which fetches  the data from mysql table and displays it in the same page with checkbox.

```
<input type="radio" name="id" value="1">
<input type="radio" name="id" value="2">
```

```
<script>
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $('input[name=id]').change(function (){
                        var var_name = $(this).val();
                        console.log(var_name);
                        $.getJSON("ServletCode", "id="+var_name,function(data){                            
                            var myValues = data.toHtml;            
                          $("#guts").html(myValues);

                        });
                    });
                });        

            </script>
```

My servlet code is:

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
username = rs.getString("name");
id = rs.getString("userid");
myList.add(username); 
myList.add(userid);                
jsonObj.put("toHtml", myList.toArray());
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.getWriter().write(jsonObj.toString());
```

i want to create a table using these values "id" and "name" and a check box. when check box is clicked i need to display his "marks" fetched from mysql again.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, your JSON will be

```
{"toHtml":["someNameValue", "someUserId"]}
```

However, if you're going to have multiple username-id pairs, those probably need their own JSON object. It will be easier to iterate over them

What you'll want to do is use javascript to create a table

```
var table = "<table>";
table += "<thead><tr><th>username</th><th>id</th></tr></thead>";
table += "<tbody>";
// loop through the array elements and create rows
table += "</tr><td>" + /* get the username from the json */ + "</td>";
table += "<td>" + /* get the userid from the json */ + "</td>";
// add a javascript callback to a checkbox to display the grades in a similar way
// done loop
table += "</tbody>";
```

You can then append this table to some other html element and make it visible.